# apply to multiple column to an argument

Tags: r, dataset, plyr, apply

I have large set will a number of variables:

```
set.seed (14)
pool = sample (c("AA","AB", "BB"), 100, replace = T) 
mydf <- data.frame (M1= pool[1:10], M2= pool[11:20],
M3= pool[21:30], M4= pool[31:40],  M5= pool[41:50], 
  M6= pool[51:60],  M7= pool[61:70], M8 = pool[71:80], 
  M9 = pool[81:90],  M10 = pool[91:100])
```

Need to install the package "hapassoc", if previously installed.

> install.packages("hapassoc")

```
>  library(hapassoc)
> example1.haplos <- pre.hapassoc(mydf, numSNPs = 3, allelic= F)

Haplotypes will be based on the following SNPs (genotypic format): 
 M8, M9, M10 
Remaining variables are: 
 M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7
```

It is taking last 3 variables in group. But 1 want apply this function by breaking data into smaller pieces by group -

```
M1, M2, M3   group 1
M4, M5       group 2
M6, M7, M8   group 3
M9, M10      group 4
```

Thus numSNPs would be represented by the following vector:

```
nsp <- c(3, 2, 3, 2)
```

I want to preserve the $haploMat for each group

```
example1.haplos$haploMat
 haplo1 haplo2
1    hBBA   hBAB
3    hAAB   hABB
4    hABA   hABA
6    hAAA   hBBA
7    hAAA   hAAA
8    hBBA   hBBB
9    hABB   hBBB
10   hABA   hBAB
12   hAAA   hBBB
13   hAAB   hBBA
14   hABA   hABA
15   hAAB   hBAB
```

The final output have eight columns group1.haplo1, goup1.haplo2, group2.haplo1, group2.haplo2, group3.haplo1, group4.haplo1, group4.haplo2.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after? (specify the column numbers of the groups as elements of the list assigned to `grps`). You'll need the `reshape2` package installed. You could do something similar with `rbind.fill()` from the `plyr` package.

```
set.seed (14)
pool = sample (c("AA","AB", "BB"), 100, replace = T) 
mydf <- data.frame (M1= pool[1:10], M2= pool[11:20],
M3= pool[21:30], M4= pool[31:40],  M5= pool[41:50], 
  M6= pool[51:60],  M7= pool[61:70], M8 = pool[71:80], 
  M9 = pool[81:90],  M10 = pool[91:100])

library(hapassoc)

grps <- list(1:3, 4:5, 6:8, 9:10)
haplos <- lapply(grps, function(x) {
    out <- pre.hapassoc(mydf[, x], numSNPs=length(x), allelic=F, 
      verbose=F)$haploMat
    row.names(out) <- as.numeric(row.names(out))
    out
})
haplos <- lapply(haplos, t)
library(reshape2)
haplos <- melt(haplos,value.name='haplotype')
haplos <- dcast(haplos, Var2 ~ L1 + Var1, value.var='haplotype')
```

RESULT

```
haplos

   Var2 1_haplo1 1_haplo2 2_haplo1 2_haplo2 3_haplo1 3_haplo2 4_haplo1 4_haplo2
1     1     hABA     hABB      hBA      hBA     hAAA     hAAB      hAA      hAA
2     2     <NA>     <NA>      hAB      hAB     hAAB     hABB      hAA      hAA
3     3     hBAA     hAAB      hBA      hBB     hBBB     hBAA      hAA      hBA
4     4     hBBB     hBAA      hBA      hAB     <NA>     <NA>      hAB      hBB
5     5     <NA>     <NA>      hBB      hAA     hABB     hAAA      hAB      hBB
6     6     hABB     hBBB      hBA      hBB     hABA     hAAB      hBB      hBB
7     7     hBBB     hBBB      hAA      hAA     hBBB     hBAA      hAB      hBB
8     8     hBBB     hABA      hBA      hAB     <NA>     <NA>      hAA      hAA
9     9     <NA>     <NA>      hBB      hAA     hAAB     hAAB      hAA      hAB
10   10     hBBB     hBAA      hAA      hBA     hABB     hBBB      hAB      hAB
11   11     <NA>     <NA>      hBB      hBB     hBBA     hBBB     <NA>     <NA>
12   12     hBBB     hABA      hAB      hBB     hABA     hABB     <NA>     <NA>
13   13     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     hABB     hBAA     <NA>     <NA>
14   14     hABB     hBBB     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
15   15     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     hAAB     hBBA     <NA>     <NA>
16   16     hBAA     hABA     <NA>     <NA>     hAAA     hBBB     <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I would like to accept this answer however I am not getting what I need in the final line:haplos <- dcast(haplos, Var2 ~ L1 + Var1, value.var='haplotype'), I also tried value_var = "haplotype" - but did give an error

Comment: @John I've edited to include the complete code that works for me. This is with hapassoc_1.2.4 and reshape2_1.2.1. If you're still getting an error, could you add it as a comment?

Comment: thanks, I was using reshape2_1.2.1 and  hapassoc_1.2-4 under older R version, but with newer version of R is works, thanks ...reason unknown